# How can I make snake game detect collision with its tail?

Tags: javascript

I am currently struggling with collision detection while writing a JavaScript Snake game using 2d canvas. Which is fairly new to me. The collision detection towards the edges works as expected. However, I run into trouble when it comes to detecting whether the snake hits itself.

I have been looking at other similar topics, but did not find them directly applicable to my case.

Below you'll find the game loop, snake object, and the collision detection functions. Any pointers to why the collision detection does not trigger when the snake hits itself, would be much appreciated.

[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Northern-Web/Sanke)

```
// Game loop

function GameLoop() {
  map.DrawMap();
  map.DrawSnake(snake);
  map.DrawFood(food);
  RenderScore();

  snake.IncrementTail();
  snake.DirectionChange(map);

  if (snake.EatFood(food, map)){
    IncrementScore();
    snake.maxLength++;
    food = Food.GetRandomFood(map);
  }

  if (!snake.isOutOfBounds(map) && !snake.IsTouchingItself()) {
  setTimeout(GameLoop, REFRESH_RATE);
  }
}
```

At the end of the GameLoop, I the game should check for `snake.isOutOfBounds(map)` and `snake.IsTouchingItself()`. Second of which, is not triggering as expected.

```
 // Snake object

  export class Snake {
  constructor(map) {
    this.positions = [{
      x: map.GetBlockSize() * 5,
      y: map.GetBlockSize() * 5
    },
    {
      x: map.GetBlockSize() * 4,
      y: map.GetBlockSize() * 5
    },
    {
      x: map.GetBlockSize() * 3,
      y: map.GetBlockSize() * 5
    }],
    this.colorBody = '#45b6fe',
    this.colorHead = '#0e2433',
    this.d,
    this.maxLength = 3,
    this.moves = 0

  }

  isOutOfBounds(map){
    if (   this.positions[0].x >= map.width
        || this.positions[0].x < 0
        || this.positions[0].y >= map.height
        || this.positions[0].y < 0
      ){
        console.log('Snake is attempting to flee.');
        return true;
      }
  }

  EatFood(food, map){
    if (  this.positions[0].x == food.x
       && this.positions[0].y == food.y){
         return true;
       } else {
         return false;
       }
   }

   IncrementTail(){
     var position = { x: this.positions[0].x,
                      y: this.positions[0].y };

     this.positions.unshift(position);
     if (this.positions.length > this.maxLength){
       this.positions.pop()
     }
   }

   IsTouchingItself(){
     for (var i = 2; i < this.positions.length; i++){
       if (this.positions[0].x === this.positions[i].x
        && this.positions[0].y === this.positions[i].y){
          console.log('Snake is touching itself!');
          return true;
        } else {
          console.log('Snake is well raised.');
          return false;
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: If you click `edit` and then `[<>]`  snippet editor, you can make a [mcve]

Comment: Is there any place in which you update each position's position? I cant seem to find it. How do you render movement?

Comment: The head is moving position, the tail follows along. Please see the IncrementTail() in the snake object.

Comment: Rendering of the snake happens within a Map object, with the following function:

  DrawSnake(snake) {
    for (let i = 0; i < snake.positions.length; i++) {
      this.ctx.fillStyle = (i == 0) ? snake.colorBody : snake.colorHead;
      this.ctx.fillRect(snake.positions[i].x, snake.positions[i].y, this.GetBlockSize(), this.GetBlockSize());

    }

Comment: I have added a link to a GitHub repo in the description, that I've created for the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check if the head's position matches a body part's position.

```
//I guess the snake's head is the first element in this.positions (index 0)
isSnakeDead() {
    //Creating the variables for simplicity
    let headX = this.positions[0].x;
    let headY = this.positions[0].y;

    //The for loop starts from 1 because the head is index 0
    //and you don't want to check if the head collides with itself
    for (let i = 1; i < this.positions.length; ++i) {
        //Another variables for simplicity
        let currentX = this.positions[i].x;
        let currentY = this.positions[i].y;

        if (headX === currentX && headY === currentY) {
            //The head collides with the current body part
            return true;
        }
    }
    //If the function reaches here then 
    //the head does not collide with any of the other parts
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Although I thought this looked exactly like the existing implementation in snake.IsTouchingSelf(), it worked like a charm. During further comparison between these two, I realized that the difference seems to be that you dropped the else statement and returned false outside of the for loop. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I actually didn't look through your entire code so I didn't see the isTouchingItself() method. I'm glad this was helpful @MichaelSagnes.